# /bin/bash -c with subshell as part of command

Tags: git, bash

I want to find out if there are any files uncommitted with Git, the only way I have access to the system is by passing a command via /bin/bash -c.

For example:
`/bin/bash -c [[ $(git status --porcelain 2>/dev/null | wc -l) == 0 ]] && echo "done"`

Sadly all variations I can come up with fail. The above command fails with:
`"sh: 1: [[: not found
"`

It looks like it's executing the results of wc -l. How can I solve this?

Thanks

Ben

Comment: `[[: not found`, like `sh:`, indicates that the shell being used is `sh`, not `bash`.

Comment: BTW, the `1` in the error message is the line number where the error occurs, not the output of `wc -l`.

Comment: If you just want to see whether your git status command produced any output, you can use `git status --porcelain 2>/dev/null | grep -q . || echo done` - `grep -q` returns success if any pattern matches and `.` matches any character. [Recommended reading](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#wc)

Comment: ...or, more efficiently: `git status --porcelain 2>/dev/null | { read && [[ $REPLY ]]; }`, avoiding the need for any external tool (and -- like the `grep -q` approach -- reading not more than a single line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quotes!

```
/bin/bash -c [[ $(git status --porcelain 2>/dev/null | wc -l) == 0 ]] && echo "done"
```

...doesn't pass the entire string after the `-c` to `bash`, as you might think. Instead, the shell interpreting this command runs expansions such as `$()` itself, and only passes content before the `&&` to bash, performing the `echo` itself.

Fixing this, one gets:

```
/bin/bash -c '(( $(git status --porcelain 2>/dev/null | wc -l) == 0 )) && echo "done"'
```

If that still doesn't work, then you're mistaken in believing that your code is being run with `bash -c`; instead, it's being run with `sh -c`, and requires some different changes to be compatible.

```
/bin/sh -c '[ "$(git status --porcelain 2>/dev/null | wc -l)" -eq 0 ] && echo "done"'
```

Specifically:

- Using the POSIX-compatible `[` command rather than `[[ ]]` (bash-extended syntax for string comparisons) or `(( ))` (bash-extended syntax for numeric comparisons).
- Double-quoting the expansions on either side of the test operator
- Using the POSIX-compatible numeric equality operator `-eq` rather than the `==` (which is (1) a bash extension not guaranteed by the POSIX spec, and (2) for *string* comparison, not *numeric* comparison).

Comment: Thanks, that sounds very logical but I'm guessing the response `/bin/bash: (( $(git status --porcelain 2>/dev/null | wc -l) == 0 )) && echo "done": No such file or directory`

Comment: That's consistent with what you'd get if you weren't passing a `-c`.

Comment: My logs appear to be correct - `exec_start: /bin/bash -c '(( $(git status --porcelain 2>/dev/null | wc -l) == 0 )) && echo \"done\"'`

Comment: Question: Can you reproduce the issue from the command line? If the code I'm giving you works at the command line, then we've proved that the issue is environmental in nature.

Comment: If you want to figure out what's up with your environment -- `sysdig -v evt.type=execve` would be ideal; `strace -s 2048 -e execv -f /path/to/command-that-starts-this-command` is a fallback if you don't have sysdig.

Comment: Yes, it works on the cmd. I will try the sysdig approach tomorrow.  thanks for your help.

Comment: To be clear, by the way -- the single-quotes are syntax targeted for the outer shell. If you're actually passing a literal argument vector in (via a non-shell language), such that there _is_ no outer shell, then the single-quotes don't apply. Also, your question should be showing the *real* code you're using to invoke this shell, in whatever language it's written in.